# Places I never knew existed vs places I never knew they existed

Tags: grammar

1. They are some places I never knew existed but they do and even look nice
2. They are some places I never knew they existed but do and even look nice
3. They are some places I never knew existed but do and even look nice

Which sentence sounds more natural? Never know what to choose...

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 3):

I find 1) the most natural, but it would be even better with *they* repeated again before *even look nice*.

3) is comprehensible, and I think it is even grammatical, but I find it odd, because by the time I get to *but*, I've forgotten which verb *do* is supposed to coordinate with.

2) doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Your comment helped me a lot!

Comment: *He's an old friend I never met but wrote to every week when we were teenager penpals* seems to be pretty much the same kind of "excessive deletion" as OP's example #3. My version seems at least *slightly* less "odd", which I think may be to do with the fact that with just the "helper" verb ***do*** we have to overtax ourselves remembering and mentally repeating not just the missing *subject* *(**they**)*, but also the main verb itself *(**existed => exist**)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: no, it's not the same, because in your example _wrote_ coordinates with _never met_, not with _He's_

Answer (score 0):

Choice 3. Choice 1 sounds okay as well (in US-English), but not choice 2.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer with more explanation, and perhaps alternate examples?